# neo4j REST API sysinfo

Tags: neo4j, nosql

Is there REST API for getting aggregated sysinfo about neo4j cluster?
Like querying ":sysinfo" in cypher.

I tried http://neo4j_db_host:7474/db/manage but there isn't enough information.

Comment: Look at this: https://glennsarti.github.io/blog/powershell-neo4j-metrics/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following query:

```
curl -u neo4j -v http://neohost:7474/db/manage/server/jmx/domain/org.neo4j > sysinfo.json
```

Comment: yes, I found that API and now use it.
But I was looking for nice API that allow me to get the same aggregated data as ":sysinfo", I mean in one query.